# NetSuite SuiteTalk ReturnAuthorization

Tags: return, authorization, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to create a Return Authorization from a Sales Order but can not determine the required parameters.

I keep receiving an error of:

> You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.

If I attempt to include the id of one of the line items in the sales order I receive the following error:

> Savon::SOAPFault ((soapenv:Server.userException) 
>   com.netledger.util.schemabean.NLSchemaBeanException: id not found on 
>   {urn:customers_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com} 
>       ReturnAuthorizationItem

This is my current request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" 
xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:tranCust="urn:customers_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <env:Header>
    <platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
      <platformCore:account>1234_SB1</platformCore:account>
        <platformCore:consumerKey>***FILTERED***</platformCore:consumerKey>
        <platformCore:token>***FILTERED***</platformCore:token>
        <platformCore:nonce>s975gqhodufgodiueroh</platformCore:nonce>
        <platformCore:timestamp>1531918396</platformCore:timestamp>
        <platformCore:signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">p0z56JDUsN+ksjhfe8HEhdEU(WJff7u+0Yee7Axk=
        </platformCore:signature>
    </platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
    <platformMsgs:preferences>
      <platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>true</platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>
    </platformMsgs:preferences>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <platformMsgs:add>
      <platformMsgs:record xsi:type="tranCust:ReturnAuthorization">
        <tranCust:entity internalId="173436">
          <platformCore:name>C030420 John Thomas</platformCore:name>
        </tranCust:entity>
        <tranCust:itemList>
          <tranCust:item>
            <tranCust:id>21354</tranCust:id>
          </tranCust:item>
        </tranCust:itemList>
      </platformMsgs:record>
    </platformMsgs:add>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If anybody could offer any guidance it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, its suppose to be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" 
xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:tranCust="urn:customers_2016_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <env:Header>
    <platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
      <platformCore:account>1234_SB1</platformCore:account>
        <platformCore:consumerKey>***FILTERED***</platformCore:consumerKey>
        <platformCore:token>***FILTERED***</platformCore:token>
        <platformCore:nonce>s975gqhodufgodiueroh</platformCore:nonce>
        <platformCore:timestamp>1531918396</platformCore:timestamp>
        <platformCore:signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">p0z56JDUsN+ksjhfe8HEhdEU(WJff7u+0Yee7Axk=
        </platformCore:signature>
    </platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
    <platformMsgs:preferences>
      <platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>true</platformMsgs:ignoreReadOnlyFields>
    </platformMsgs:preferences>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <platformMsgs:add>
      <platformMsgs:record xsi:type="tranCust:ReturnAuthorization">
        <tranCust:entity internalId="173436">
          <platformCore:name>C030420 John Thomas</platformCore:name>
        </tranCust:entity>
        <tranCust:itemList>
          <tranCust:item>
            <tranCust:item internalId="22138" type="inventoryItem"/>
          </tranCust:item>
        </tranCust:itemList>
      </platformMsgs:record>
    </platformMsgs:add>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a initialize for the same.
So once the Sales order is created then we can do a Authorization Return on it once it successfully goes through the process.

More info at : https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3508536.html

Make sure the SOAPAction is set to initialize.
[image]